# Creating Grouping from time windows in SQL Server (Group and Island)

Tags: sql-server, time, grouping, window-functions, rank

I have a table with a schedule for each agent. I need to group the timings of the same schedule event from multiple entries to a single entry for the same block.

For example, the highlighted ***Support*** and ***Admin*** sessions back to back can be grouped into one row. See below example:

[image]

Rows 9 and 10 need to be grouped into single row by taking the earliest startDt and the latest EndDt. Same again for for lines 12,13,14.

Resulting in:

[image]

Ive tried using the window functions such as row_number(), RANK(), LAG, LEAD but none of these are effective at dealing with this dilemma. Any clues would be great.

Thanks.

EDIT. Also just to add the grouping method doesn't fit the solution as the grouping would apply to the whole list rather than just the 'local block'.

Comment: Why not use `MIN(StartTime), MIN(StartDt), MAX(EndDt)`, then group by the first three columns?

Comment: @BJones This wouldnt work as it would group across all of the categories in the list. So for 'Admin' it would pick up the first admin startDt (06/01/2021 10:00:00) and the last EndDt(06/01/2021 14:40:00) - which of course is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Use **Group BY**

```
SELECT CID,STATE,[DESC],MIN(StartTime),MIN(StartDt),MAX(StartDt)
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY CID,STATE,[DESC]
```

Comment: Again same as the answer above, this will group across all the 'admins' regardless of where they are in the list. It does appear like a simple solution but much more difficult in reality.